# JDBC SQL Server Decimal "invented" precision

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql, jdbc, bigdecimal

Note: This could be running with SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, or MySQL database. But for this example I am just using SQL Server. The solution needs to be generic enough to apply all mentioned databases though.

In SQL Server I have a column defined as `decimal(32, 16)`, because that column must be able to store potentially large or precise values. However, it may also store  small or imprecise values. But when I select the BigDecimal it is returned with trailing zeros that were not in the original. I assume this is because of my column definition allowing for the high precision.

*I do not want any values to be stored or returned with "invented" scale/precision, but I still need to allow for that large scale/precision.*

```
// ... set up ... 
// precision 2, scale 2
BigDecimal bdInsert = new BigDecimal("0.51");
preparedStatement.insertBigDecimal(1, bdInsert);
// ... insert/commit ... select ...
// precision 0, scale 16 <-- Grrrrrrr!
BigDecimal bdResult = resultSet.getBigDecimal(1);
System.out.println(bdResult);
// prints "0.5100000000000000" <-- Grrrrrrr!
```

Does SQL Server not store, or JDBC not send nor select, the precision and scale of the inserted BigDecimal?

I can't just go truncating the zeros because it is possible that a BigDecimal was stored with trailing zeros to indicate that it is precise.

```
// "0.510000" indicating that this value is accurate to the 6th place
BigDecimal bdPrecise = new BigDecimal("0.510000");
preparedStatement.insertBigDecimal(1, bdPrecise);

// precision 0, scale 16 
BigDecimal bdResult = resultSet.getBigDecimal(1);

System.out.println(bdResult);
// prints "0.5100000000000000" loses information

System.out.println(bdResult.stripTrailingZeros());
// prints "0.51", loses information

// What I want is "0.510000"
```

**Is there a way, either through SQL Server or JDBC to get the scale/precision of the original BigDecimal?**

Please don't tell me I would have to make a separate column to store this information...

I guess an alternative would be to just insert/select the BigDecimals as Strings then parse it from the String like `new BigDecimal(val)`. But I would prefer storing as a decimal.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at using a [`sql_variant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql) column?

Comment: @HABO Looks interesting. However, I forgot to mention that this code could be used on a multitude of databases and the solution should be generic enough to be able to work across SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, or MySQL databases. (So mainly just ANSI SQL) Quite constraining I know. Updating question to include this requirement.

Comment: Had a similar situation years ago where the precison varied and also acted as an indicator.  It was a bit of a hack, but I stored the values as VARCHAR  so 0.510000 was stored with the trailing zeros

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Yea.. that was my alternative idea. It's a real shame that they don't store the original scale/precision

Comment: A `decimal(32, 16)` by definition has a scale of 16, so the behavior is expected and even required by the SQL standard. For DB2 you might want to look at using `DECFLOAT` instead (it is specified in SQL:2016, but as far as I'm aware, currently only supported in DB2).

Answer (score 1):

The following code demonstrates the `sql_variant` data type in SQL Server. (And how to display data type information about an expression.) Since the solution needs to apply to *anything capable of holding bits* it won't address all of your issues, but it may be of some value.

I suspect that the only solution that will work across "all" platforms is a string, possibly containing XML with an explicit precision.

```
declare @Samples as Table ( Value sql_variant );
insert into @Samples ( Value ) values
  ( Cast( 3.14 as Decimal( 10, 2 ) ) );
insert into @Samples ( Value ) values
  ( Cast( 3.14 as Decimal( 10, 3 ) ) );
insert into @Samples ( Value ) values
  ( Cast( 3.14 as Decimal( 10, 4 ) ) );
insert into @Samples ( Value ) values
  -- NB: Both values are inserted with scale 5 when they are included in a single INSERT.
  ( Cast( 42 as Decimal( 10, 1 ) ) ),
  ( Cast( 42 as Decimal( 10, 5 ) ) );
insert into @Samples ( Value ) values
  ( Cast( 1.618 as Decimal( 10, 6 ) ) );
insert into @Samples ( Value ) values
  ( 'Edgar' );

select Value, SQL_Variant_Property( Value, 'BaseType' ) as BaseType,
  SQL_Variant_Property( Value, 'Precision' ) as Precision,
  SQL_Variant_Property( Value, 'Scale' ) as Scale
  from @Samples;
```

(Then there was the steel mill where they wanted a dot between the inches and sixteenths, e.g. 23 3/4 inches was displayed as "23.12". Handling "36.1" and "36.10" as differing by 9/16 on input and output? Oy.)

Comment: Interesting stuff, hopefully useful to others who see this. I had no idea about it since I primarily play with boring ol' ANSI Sql.